# Convertir Array en Matriz Tridimensional [PHP]

Tags: php, array, string, object

Tengo el siguiente Array:

```
array(9) { [0]=> string(6) "Tomate" [1]=> string(3) "333" [2]=> string(4) "Kgs." [3]=> string(5) "Huevo" [4]=> string(5) "12200" [5]=> string(2) "U." [6]=> string(12) "Carne Picada" [7]=> string(3) "100" [8]=> string(4) "Kgs." }
```

Me gustaria obtener, a partir del array anterior (siempre van a tener una cantidad de elementos múltiplo de tres) una estructura iterable que agrupe de a 3 elementos a partir del comienzo del array, por ejemplo:

```
{
[
0 = Tomate,
1 = 333,
2 = Kgs.
],
[
0 = Huevo,
1 = 12200,
2 = U.
],
[
0 = Carne Picada
1 = 100
2 = Kgs.
]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

esto lo puedes hacer con la función array_chunk ([https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-chunk.php)), donde el primer parámetro es el Array a trabajar (tu entrada) y el segundo es el tamaño de elementos que quieres por cada lote.

```
$array = ["Tomate", 333, "Kgs.", "Huevo", 12200, "U.", "Carne Picada", 333, "Kgs."];
$nuevoArray = array_chunk($array, 3);
```